# How to detect an app crash in android when running Automated Tests against them?

Tags: android, appium, crash

I use Appium to Automate and Test the Mobile Apps. There will be many occasions where the App crashes because of a bug in it and then the Test fails. Test failures can be because of many reasons but failures because of an app crash should be identified and reported in the Test Report Properly. I want to know if there is any way we can detect an app crash in an Automated fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a small code to capture logcat from device continously (or at intervals). Filter out the keywords for exception and failures in the logcat related to your app. If crash keyword is detected then you can take a copy of the entire logcat and attach it with your test report. If you know java very well this strategy should not be very complex to implement.

Comment: Is there any example of this kind of implementation?

Answer (score 3):

Using Appium java-client, you could use the android driver method currentActivity()
This tells you what activity is currently frontmost on the device. If the app has crashed then currentActivity won't return any activities from your app.

Javadoc here: http://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver.html#currentActivity()

Example code:

```
String activity = driver.currentActivity();
if (!activity.equals("com.myapp.myactivity")){
    log("App crashed!");
}
```

You could put this check inside a test watcher that gets called when there is a test failure. This way you can log more details and highlight potential crashes. If you're using jUnit, you could use http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html

Comment: This method is way better than parsing adb logcat output

Comment: This won't work in cases when 'App has stopped' dialog is displayed